# Issue when executing JQuery function after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to hide the parent of an `input` after performing my Ajax call but it's not working for some reason, that is no effect happens and the parent is not hidden.

**Here's my JQuery snippet:**

```
$( ".getqty" ).mouseover(function() {
    var split = this.id.split(":");
    var color = split[0];
    var size = split[1];
    var prodID = split[2];

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to loadstuff.php
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/loadstuff.php',             
        dataType: 'html',   //expect html to be returned   
        data:'color='+color+'&size='+size+'&prodID='+prodID,     
        success: function(response){                   
             $(this).parent().hide();  //Problematic part
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

**This is my HTML:**

```
<a href='#'>
    <input class='getqty id='a:b:c' type='text'>
</a>
```

What I'm trying to do might seem pointless but it's actually me trying to understand why hiding the parent does not work on hover.

**However I tried the following and hid the parent before the ajax call and it worked. I don't understand why.**

```
$( ".getqty" ).mouseover(function() {
    var split = this.id.split(":");
    var color = split[0];
    var size = split[1];
    var prodID = split[2];
    $(this).parent().hide(); //Moved it here and it works. But I need it after the ajax call

$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to loadstuff.php
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'includes/loadstuff.php',             
    dataType: 'html',   //expect html to be returned   
    data:'color='+color+'&size='+size+'&prodID='+prodID,     
    success: function(response){                   

    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(thrownError);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` is moved outside of the original function call. You can give it a variable so its attached to the correct selector. Something like:

```
$( ".getqty" ).mouseover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var split = this.id.split(":");
    var color = split[0];
    var size = split[1];
    var prodID = split[2];


    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to loadstuff.php
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/loadstuff.php',             
        dataType: 'html',   //expect html to be returned   
        data:'color='+color+'&size='+size+'&prodID='+prodID,     
        success: function(response){                   
             $this.parent().hide();  //Problematic part
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this)` refers to a different object:

```
success: function(response){                   
     $(this).parent().hide();  //Problematic part
},
```

So change your code this way:

```
$( ".getqty" ).mouseover(function() {
    var split = this.id.split(":");
    var color = split[0];
    var size = split[1];
    var prodID = split[2];
    var $this = $(this);                                        // Add this

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to loadstuff.php
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/loadstuff.php',             
        dataType: 'html',   //expect html to be returned   
        data:'color='+color+'&size='+size+'&prodID='+prodID,     
        success: function(response){                   
             $this.parent().hide();                         // Change here.
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```